# Blender 2.76 on Mac mini 09 MacOS 10.11.6 + 10.13.6 + Mac mini + 2 x MBP (3) MacOS 11.6

Tags: rendering

I want to build a render farm. I have 5 Macs as follows Mac mini '09 running 10.11.6 Blender says I can only run up to Blender 2.76, a MBP 2011 running 10.13.6 and For Blender 3.0 I have 1 x 2014 Mac Mini and 2 x 2017 MBP all running MacOS 11.6

Does anyone know if a render farm like this can render files together? Will Blender divide the work by ability?

So that the demanding tasks are done by the newer machines and other functions are done by the older machines.

Would some additional coding need to be done to do that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

Blender does indeed support "kind of" renderfarms pretty easy.

All you have to do is set your output path to the same cloud directory on your macs and uncheck overwrite and check placeholders. By this Blender checks automatically whether the frame which should be rendered is already there or not. If not, it creates the frame-file (e.g. 0001.png) as placeholder and the next machine which starts to render the same blend file will skip each frame, which is already in that same directory and start with the next not rendered frame.

This is not a "real" renderfarm where a master talks to clients, but i think for the "normal" users at home it is pretty satisfying.

Additional info for real renderfarms: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/network-render-farm-in-2-80/6777/2

[image]